# GAE Access Restriction only to Taskqueue and cron

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing an application on GAE/J.

I want some of my APIs can be executed only from task queue and cron.

`X-AppEngine-QueueName` request header can be user for task queue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033272/google-app-engine-task-queue-and-users-service), but I can not find the way for cron.

How can I check whether my API is called from cron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such requests will have a header `X-Appengine-Cron`.